# Assigning PK from another datasource as a PK in new application / model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a dashboard application where I'm importing data from various databases into a new ASP.Net MVC application/database.  I'd like to maintain the source system(s) data structure's.  Is there a way to assign the PK from the imported data source's to the PK of a model in my application?  Essentially mimicking the source system data structure?

I'm using entity framework code first approach for building out the database as I go.  Below is the current models.

```
public class PageStats
{
    public int PageStatsId { get; set; }
    public string Metric { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int PageViews { get; set; }
    public int UniquePageViews { get; set; }
    public double AvgSessionDuration { get; set; }
    public double AvgTimeOnPage { get; set; }
    public string TopicSectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual TopicSection TopicSection { get; set; }

}

public class TopicSection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TopicSectionId { get; set; }
    public string TopicSectionName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to export the data structures from the source database(s) and recreate this in the dashboard database?  

Or are you asking if you can maintain the PK-FK relationship across databases?

Comment: I'm reading in data from a csv file where the pk is available for saving to the 'new' database table.    Rather than letting EF create a new PK and saving the source PK as an additional field, it would be nice to use the source PK as the newly created object PK.  This is a dashboard so I won't be doing any crud ops on the data via forms or anything.  I'm assuming its faster for the query to lookup the PK rather than a field string compare.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server:

when you create the 'new' database table, do not include an identity definition on the PK column.  This will allow you to load the data from the CSV file into the new table without SQL assigning a new value to the PK field.

If you are using designing the tables with EF EDMX, select the TopicSection.Id field, and turn off the identity field definition (set "Entity Key" parameter to false).

Comment: Whoops, should have mentioned that I'm using Entity Framework Code First Approach for building out the database as I go.  So is there a property attribute override I need to use?

Comment: Can you show the code that creates your table?  You likely need to remove the identity definition, which could be a data annotation that looks like this: [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)].

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Posted the models above.  The code reads in the data as records into the  PageStats Object.  I build up an ICollection<PageStats>, then save them to the db.  I'm saving the TopicSectionId to the PageStats object as an FK with a virtual navigation property.  Right now I'm having EF create a new PK and saving the TopicSectionId as a field.  I want to assign the TopicSectionId as the PK for the TopicSection class/model/table.  I'm thinking theres a way to put an attribute above TopicSectionId that tells EF to use the property/field as the PK...?

Comment: Getting closer.  In your DbContext class, do you have code that tells EF to create TopicSection.Id as an identity field?   Or are you managing the table design with an EDMX file?  You need to disable the identity field spec there, and then you will be able to assign a value to TopicSection.Id yourself.